# Unable to restart Cloudera management service

Tags: cloudera, restart

I am trying to restart cloudera management service using cloudera manager, but I am unable to start, getting time-out error. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after analyzing logs and exceptions found, I restarted Agent. Cloudera Management services started gracefully.